# Trying to calculate num of teams with leftover players using functions

Tags: c++, function

I don't get any errors when writing the code but as soon as I compile and run through the program I get a run time error. The error comes when attempting to calculate number of teams and leftover players. I tried placing variable in different sections but it seem if i take out the `printResult` function everything seems to work. other than not being able to calculate.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int GetPlayersPerTeam();

int GetTotalPlayersAvailable();

int CalculateNumberOfTeamsAndLeftover(int players, int numTeams, int leftOver, int teamPlayers);

void PrintResults(int numTeams, int leftOver);

int main()
{
    int teamPlayers, players, numTeams, leftOver;

    teamPlayers = GetPlayersPerTeam();

    players = GetTotalPlayersAvailable();

    numTeams, leftOver = CalculateNumberOfTeamsAndLeftover(players, numTeams, leftOver, 
    teamPlayers);

    PrintResults(numTeams, leftOver);

}

    int GetPlayersPerTeam()
{
    int teamPlayers;

    cout << "How many players do you wish per team?" << endl;
    cout << "(Enter a value in the range 9 - 15): "; cin >> teamPlayers;

    while (teamPlayers < 9 || teamPlayers > 15)
    {
        cout << "You should have at least 9 but no" << endl;
        cout << "more than 15 per team." << endl;
        cout << "How many players do you wish per team?: "; cin >> teamPlayers;
    }

    return teamPlayers;
}

int GetTotalPlayersAvailable()
{
    int players;

    cout << "How many players are available?: "; cin >> players;

    while (players < 1)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a positive number: "; cin >> players;
    }

    return players;
}

int CalculateNumberOfTeamsAndLeftover(int players, int numTeams, int leftOver, int teamPlayers)
{
    numTeams = players / teamPlayers;
    leftOver = players % teamPlayers;

    return numTeams;
    return leftOver;

}

void PrintResults(int numTeams, int leftOver)
{

    cout << "There will be " << numTeams << " teams with ";
    cout << leftOver << " players left over.\n";

}
```

Comment: This is the error that I get:

"Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'leftOver' is being used without being initialized. occurred"

Comment: That is a great error message. I'd have killed for that when I was learning to program. What it means to you is you need to look for where `leftOver` is first used and ensure that it has a good value. However in this case, you're better off asking yourself if you need to pass it in to `CalculateNumberOfTeamsAndLeftover` at all. Note: You can only have one `return` statement in a function. You can get sneaky and aggregate the two values in a single data structure that can be returned with a single `return` or you can start playing with pass by reference.

Comment: `numTeams, leftOver = CalculateNumberOfTeamsAndLeftover(players, numTeams, leftOver, teamPlayers)`      You're trying to somehow return two values from a function.   C++ doesn't work that way.  A function can only return a single value.    Since the code is not behaving as you want, it is leaving `numTeams` uninitialised, so subsequently accessing its value gives undefined behaviour.     If you want to return multiple values, place them into a `struct`.

Comment: leftOver needs to be calculated inside of said function, it then has to be returned so that the function “printResults” can display the remainder of players. Or if there is a better way to do this I’m all ears

Comment: How would I place them into a struct?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can't return 2 things from a function, you can only return 1. One option would be to turn numTeams into a reference, which would allow you to modify it in the function body.

```cpp
int CalculateNumberOfTeamsAndLeftover(int players, int& numTeams, int leftOver, int teamPlayers)
{
    numTeams = players / teamPlayers;
    leftOver = players % teamPlayers;

    return leftOver;
}
```

Then when you call the method, you can do:

```cpp
    leftOver = CalculateNumberOfTeamsAndLeftover(players, numTeams, leftOver, 
    teamPlayers);
```

That should fix the issue.

Comment: The issue is the that I need to get two values from the variables declared earlier. In this function I need the number of full teams that I can create, and then i also need to calculate the left over amount of players in that same function, since I can only return one value, how would i return the second value so that the function  'printResults" can output both values using cout?